# How can I cause an ECONNRESET in recv() from a client?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

I am using a server that is crashing following a call to recv() returning -1 and errno set to ECONNRESET.  I originally found this condition using nmap (I'm not a cracker, was just testing if the port was open at the time.)  However, nmap uses raw sockets so I'm not too happy submitting this as a test case to the developers.  I would rather write a client program in C that can cause the ECONNRESET.

So far I have tried two things: connect() to the server from my client and then shutdown() the socket immediately after connecting.  recv() on the server still returned 1 (I have inserted debugging code so I can see the return value.)  I also tried calling send() with some string and then immediately calling shutdown().  No dice, the string was transmitted fine.

So how would I cause this condition?  Non portable is fine, I am using Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `shutdown`.  Call `close` instead.

Take a look at a TCP state diagram.

http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/debugging-tcp.html

Basically, `shutdown` closes a socket "politely" by sending a FIN and waiting for the peer to finish (FIN -> ACK/FIN -> ACK -> closed), at which point you call `close` and all is good.  If you call `close` without calling `shutdown` first, it's the "impolite" version which sends a RST -- the equivalent of hanging up in the middle of a phone call, without waiting for the other person to finish what they're saying.

Think of "shutdown" as "say goodbye", and "close" as "hang up".  You always have to hang up, but you don't have to say goodbye first.

**About nmap:** It is perfectly acceptable to give developers a test case with nmap.  That's one of the main purposes of nmap anyway.

Comment: Thanks!  Using close() instead of shutdown() works great.  One thing that was confusing me is that I have to try several times to get the ECONNRESET using close() where nmap can trigger it immediately.  But I guess nmap can just send a straight TCP RST, whereas using the high-level socket API you have to rely on OS timing to cut off the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts were correct to use `shutdown()`, however you were not using it correctly for this.

Presumably you are trying `shutdown()` with `SHUT_WR` or `SHUT_RDWR`.  When you close the writing direction, as these do, your side of the connection notifies the peer with a `FIN` - indicating that no more data will be forthcoming from your side.  This will cause `recv()` on the other side to indicate a clean end-of-file on the connection, which isn't what you want in this case.

Instead, you want to use `SHUT_RD` to shutdown the *reading* direction of the socket only, and hold it open for writing.  This will not notify the peer immediately - but if the peer sends any data after this point, your side will respond with a `RST`, to inform the peer that some data was lost - it wasn't seen by your client application.

(So, to ensure that you get a connection reset, you need to make sure that the server will be trying to send something to you - you might need to send something first, then perform the reading shutdown).